# Oracle 10g-Express Query

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle-xe

I want to perform a special query on a table in my oracle database.

I want the result to be sorted according to an enum that I have.

the enum goes as follows:

```
private enum days
{
    Saturday = 1,
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
}
```

I want the result to be sorted according to this enum.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a `SQL` question; The following reference may be helpful:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

The brute-force method is to use a case statement in your SQL; the equivallent to your snippet of code is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field1 = 'Saturday' then 1
            WHEN field1 = 'Sunday' then 2
            WHEN field1 = 'Monday' then 3
            ...
            END as dateval,
       field1 as datedisplay
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY 1;
```

The `DECODE` SQL function also works as well, but I like `CASE` because it's easier to read and avoid typos or mistakes.

If you have more information from your date values, I suggest to keep your date values intact in your database fields as a DATE data type. If you need to find out the day of the week, using the reference above, you can simply cast your date value as a character string representing the correct, corresponding day of the week value.

to test:

```
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'DAY') as day_of_week
  FROM dual;
```

yields:

```
WEDNESDAY
(or whatever day of the week is local to your system)
```

Keep in mind that whatever is returned from the to_char function is case sensitive. This should work on all editions of Oracle, including Oracle-XE.